# Dinitz’ algorithm in simple unit-capacity networks

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, network-flow, bipartite-matching, bipartite-graph

I am studying for an algorithm design course, and can't understand this demonstration about how Dinitz’ algorithm computes a maximum flow in $O(m \sqrt{n})$ time.

This is what is written on the slides I am reading:

> Theorem. [Even–Tarjan 1975] In simple unit-capacity networks,  Dinitz’
> algorithm computes a maximum flow in $O(m \sqrt{n})$ time.
>
> Pf.
>
> ・Lemma 1.
> Each phase of normal augmentations takes $O(m)$ time.
>
> ・Lemma 2. After $\sqrt{n}$ phases, $val( f ) ≥ val( f *) – \sqrt{n}$.
>
> ・Lemma 3. After $≤ \sqrt{n}$ additional augmentations, flow is optimal.

I think I get the first lemma: normal augmentation phase takes up to $O(m)$ because this is the cost of generating a level graph $L_G$. However, I have not understood what exactly happens after the "normal" augmentation (in what does the "special" augmentation phase consist? How many "phases" are needed?)

I have no clue about how the values in the other two lemmas are brought up.
Could someone help me understand it?

[Here](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ewayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/07NetworkFlowI.pdf) are the slides I am referring to, in particular the ones between 92-96

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you understand what $f^*$ is and that if your level graph has $\sqrt n$ many levels, then there is a level with at most $\sqrt n$ many vertices? Do you understand why the defined cut then has capacity at most $\sqrt n$?

Comment: $f*$ should be the maximum flow, while $f$ is the one in the current phase, I think. I don't understand what guarantees me that the definined graph will have $\sqrt{n}$ levels, but if I assume it does, than it makes sense that one level has less than $\sqrt{n}$ verticies.

Comment: Then I would look at the statement "after $\sqrt n$ iterations, the length of the shortest augmenting path is at least $\sqrt n$. Can you make sense of it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what happens after an iteration.  I understand what happens until slide 91, then the first iteration stops. How does the second one start? Does the level graph get recreated and how will it be different than before?
I think this is why I don't understand your last sentence: `after $\sqrt{n}$ iterations, the length of the shortest augmenting path is at least $\sqrt{n}$`.
I understand that there will be a level h with up to $\sqrt{n}$ verticies, and a level h+1 with more than $\sqrt{n}$ verticies. But I don't get why the number of iterations has to be $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Maybe I am confusing phase and iterations. However, I am pretty lost. Thank you really a lot for your time and patience.

Comment: Sorry, I meant phases. Regarding why $\sqrt n$; this is simply the number that makes the analysis work, and it's because it balances out the two parts. Which values $a$ and $b$ have $ab = n$ and minimizes $O(a + b)$? You can try the analysis with e.g. after $10$ iterations, but then you might have a cut of size $n/10$, so you have to run an extra $O(n)$ iterations. Or after $\log n$ phases, but then you might have to run an additional $O(n / \log n)$ phases. If you run $\sqrt n$ phases, then you only need to run an additional $n/\sqrt n = \sqrt n$ phases.

Answer (score 1):

> I have no clue about how the values in the other two lemmas are brought up.

The *how* is this: What are the values $a$ and $b$ such that $ab = n$ and $O(a + b)$ is minimized?

The answer is $\sqrt n$, and that value is *chosen* in the argument above for that precise reason.

After $\sqrt n$ phases, we know that the BFS layer graph must have *at least* $\sqrt n$ many layers, which means that there is a layer with *at most* $\sqrt n$ many vertices.  But if there is a layer with at most $\sqrt n$ many vertices, then the $s$-$t$-cut is at most $\sqrt n$ in this graph.

To see this: Let $L_i$ be a layer with $\leq \sqrt n$ many vertices.  And let $L_i^\leftarrow$ be the set of vertices in $L_i$ with *exactly one in-edge*, and let $L_i^\rightarrow$ be all other vertices in $L_i$ (they all have *exactly one out-edge* since $G$ is a unit-capacity network).  Notice that $L_i^\leftarrow, L_i^\rightarrow$ partitions $L_i$.

Now, let $A$ be the set of vertices in layers $L_j$ for $j < i$, plus $L_i^\leftarrow$.  You should be able to draw a figure that convinces you of the fact that the capacity of the cut $A,B$ is at most $\sqrt n$.

This implies that $v(f) \geq v(f^*) - \sqrt n$.

But then, after an additional $\sqrt n$ phases, we have reached $v(f^*)$.

Hence, after at most $2\sqrt n$ phases, we have reached the optimal flow.  Since each phase can be performed in time $O(m)$, the algorithm runs in time $O(\sqrt n)$.